# Suggest a suitable Automated Testing Tool for my project

Tags: automated-tests

We are in search of an automated testing tool for our project. As we are in testing department we prefer a tool which would have less programming in it. Please suggest some tools for us .Till now we are testing our application manually. 
Our project is being developed in Java.
Is there any freeware tool that I could use or is it better to go for a paid tool?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please share with us more about your project.  Is it a Java Swing application or perhaps a web application or maybe it has no GUI at all?

Comment: isnt this question OFF TOPIC? why hasnt it been closed? surely this question will attract spam and opinionanted answers

Answer (score 1):

Less programming? You'll need something like JUnit to write unit tests if you want to do serious regression testing, but unit tests require you to write *some* code

Here's a big list of open-source testing tools, some of them may offer what you want: http://java-source.net/open-source/testing-tools/junit

For example, *T2* claims to be a random testing tool. As one, it is fully automatic, but one must keep in mind that the code coverage of random testing is in general very limited. It should be used as a complement to other testing methods. T2 checks for internal errors, run time exceptions, method specifications, and class invariant.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you mean a CI tool or not, but we use Hudson at Zappos and it works pretty well.

http://hudson-ci.org/

..and there's also CruiseControl: http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/

If you're not talking about CI, maybe you mean QA testing - in which case you should take a look at something like Selenium (for web apps):

http://seleniumhq.org/

If you're doing GUI testing? I'm not really familiar with that area, but I've heard about WinRunner and Rational:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_WinRunner
http://www-01.ibm.com/software/rational/offerings/quality/

..though neither are really free tools. Something like AutoIT might help you move widgets around, but it lacks the reporting parts:

http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml

Answer (score 0):

There could be two answer to you question:

- Besides Selenium, though it has ample of advantages, I am reading about another tool which uses same API which Selenium use. The only changes in API I have seen so far is it reduces the complexity of functions thus making it more easier and simpler for user who is learning. 
  The tool is called 'Helium' and it has 50% (and more) less complex functions and code as Selenium has.
  The only problem with this tool is it is paid tool for learning purpose and for implementing not-so-big scale project you can use it. But yeah after some time its gonna cost you.

I have implemented some code on Helium. Please let me know , if you face any issue initially or you are thinking to implement it.

- Other being, you can use Selenium Builder(http://khyatisehgal.wordpress.com/2014/05/26/selenium-builder-exporting-and-execution/) which is an advanced form of Selenium IDE. It imports your command in different languages and does work more effectively and efficiently as Selenium IDE does(http://khyatisehgal.wordpress.com/2014/05/25/selenium-builder/) . So you can import scripts in Eclipse IDE and just execute them as is.

Please let me know , if you have any doubt in any of the tool.